# How to merge multiple GeoPackage files into one file with a single layer using ogr2ogr?

Tags: layers, ogr2ogr

I'm using `ogr2ogr` in a bash script to merge multiple `gpkg` files. What I'm doing basically looks like this:

```
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append merged.gpkg input_file_1.gpkg
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append merged.gpkg input_file_2.gpkg
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append merged.gpkg input_file_3.gpkg
```

So all the `input_file_x.gpkg` end up in `merged.gpkg`. This works fine, except a new vector layer is created for every input file, which I want to avoid. As far as I understand it, the `-append` flag should take care of this.

From `man ogr2ogr`:

> -append: Append to existing layer instead of creating new

All of the input files look identical in terms of attributes and geometry type.

Comment: From `man ogr2ogr: -nln name: Assign an alternate name to the new layer`. If you have layer "foo" in the GeoPackage you can add data into that by using `-append -nln foo`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I managed to merge my files. Although this seems like a bit of a hack to me. I wonder if there's a proper solution to this.

Comment: That's how ogr2ogr is made to work. It might be possible to get the same result with ogrinfo and -SQL parameter by running something like INSERT INTO my_table VALUES ( ... but using ogr2ogr with -append and giving the name of the table where to append with -nln is the common way.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [`ogrmerge.py`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html), which is available since [GDAL/OGR 2.2.0](https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/ee535a1a3f5b35b0d231e1faac89ac1f889f7988/gdal/NEWS#L2358) ? You can run:

```
ogrmerge.py -f GPKG -o merged.gpkg *.gpkg
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented you should specify the layer name with -nln to make sure all geopackages are written to this layer.

```
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append -nln layer123 merged.gpkg input_file_1.gpkg
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append -nln layer123 merged.gpkg input_file_2.gpkg
ogr2ogr -f 'gpkg' -append -nln layer123 merged.gpkg input_file_3.gpkg
```